# Row count differs when using DATE and DATETIME

Tags: mysql, datetime, date

As the title says, the row count differs when doing a select using DATE and DATETIME. Please advise.

I'm trying to select rows between 1st and 5th Jan, 2012. The date column datatype is bigint (UNIX timestamp).

```
select * from table_name
where sample_timestamp between unix_timestamp('2012-01-01')*1000 and unix_timestamp('2012-01-05')*1000
```

If I include the time in HH:MM:SS, the rows returned are correct i.e.

```
select * from table_name
where sample_timestamp between unix_timestamp('2012-01-01 00:00:00')*1000 and unix_timestamp('2012-01-05 23:59:59')*1000
```

Any input will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can format source code with the `{}` toolbar button. I've done it for you this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'2012-01-05' is actually '2012-01-05 00:00:00' which is not what you're writing in the second select.

I suspect what you mean to do is

```
select * from table_name 
where sample_timestamp >= unix_timestamp('2012-01-01')*1000 
and sample_timestamp < unix_timestamp('2012-01-06')*1000
```

which as a bonus handles leap seconds correctly too :)

Comment: Thanks Joachim for the fast response. If I just use the date '2012-01-05' then it is '2012-01-05 00:00:00'. But if I specify the time as 23:59:59 it is till end of 5th Jan. Could you please tell me why you didn't use BETWEEN? Cheers:-)

Comment: Just that between includes both "limits" and you'd have to give it the last second of the day just as you did in your second example. If you're unlucky and searching until 23:59:59 when you're looking in logs for example, you may miss 2012-06-30 23:59:60 (yes, that leap second actually existed) or a few milliseconds after that time if the time is that granular. After being bitten once myself, I always use exclusive limits for end time if possible ;-)